# ASP.NET web application connecting to remote DB / SSRS server (Reporting Server authentication Issue)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am upgrading from a single ASP.NET web app / DB server (Windows Server 2008R2, SQL Server 2014 Web) to a stand-alone web and remote database server.

**Note**: I don't have AD or domain setup, so I'm using SQL Server authentication to sign in from the web app to the remote database server.

I have the application running, connecting to the remote database without an issue.

I now am trying to setup the SSRS Report Server functionality.

Can anyone give me pointers on what I should do in terms of authentication?

The existing `web.config` contains:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
```

I can't have it prompt for user/password. Right now the web app when trying to run a report says unauthorized.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I think what you're asking about is "anonymous" authentication for SSRS?  If so, then here are a couple of articles that will hopefully help you on your way (me, personally, I've never found myself in a position where I needed to do this, so I don't have first-hand knowledge)  https://www.swarndeep.com/2011/12/setting-up-anonymous-access-for.html   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jameswu/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008